# Calendar event to options available in choice dropdown

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, workflow, list-view, sharepoint-calendar

I have a calendar in my sharepoint site. I need to track which employees have attended the events that are added to this calendar. And show a consolidated report of this information. Is this possible?

I am thinking of adding a list with event name column of type choice. But then I can’t figure out how to link the choices available to the calendar events.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Add attendees into the Event content type.

1. Click List Settings on the Ribbon.
2. Under Content Types, click Event content types. If Content Types doesn't appear, click Advanced settings, and click Yes under Allow management of content types?, and then click OK.
3. Add from existing site or list columns.
4. In the “Available columns” list, select Attendees, and then click Add to move the selected column to the “Columns to add” list.

[How to add attendees in a SharePoint Online calendar](http://kb.cloudiway.com/how-to-add-attendees-in-a-sharepoint-online-calendar/)